# Move in only 3 different Vertical positions with 2 buttons in a javascript / html5 game

Tags: javascript, html, 2d, keydown

I'm new to html5 games and javascript and I need a little help here.

I'm creating a simple 2D mini-game, but I have a problem. With the positions.

I have 3 different vertical positions (or 3 rows), *p_top*, *p_mid* and *p_bot*. My mission is to move a ball with these positions using just 2 buttons.

My buttons are only the **up** and **down** arrow.  If I press **up** I move the red ball one position up, and if I press **down** I move the red ball one position down.

The problem:
If the ball is at *p_bot* and I want to press **up**, it goes to *p_top*. And if the ball is at *p_top* and I press **down** it goes to *p_bot*.

How can I fix this? This is what I'm doing. I'm not very sure if my algorythm at *update();* is not good, or if it is something wrong on they key event listener.

```
//Keyboard event listener
var keysDown = {};

addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    keysDown[e.keyCode] = true;
}, false);
addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
    delete keysDown[e.keyCode];
}, false);

var update = function(){
    if(38 in keysDown) { //key UP
        if(ball.y == p_bot){
            ball.y = p_mid; 
        }
        if(gninja.y == p_mid){
            ball.y = p_top;
        }
    }
    if(40 in keysDown) { //key DOWN
        if(ball.y == p_top){
            ball.y = p_mid;
        }
        if(gninja.y == p_mid){
            ball.y = p_bot;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is your update is called to fast and you don't see middle pos because when you push the key in your keysDown object, it's always in and the update is all ~16ms right ?

**First solutions:**

If you want the player have to push 2 times on up to go from bot to top you should use only keyup like this
Remove keydown listener, remove delete in the keyup:

```
addEventListener("keyup", function( e ){ keysDown[ e.keyCode ] = true; }, false );
```

Then remove the key when update check it

```
if ( 40 in keysDown )
{
  delete keysDown[ 40 ];
  // do you old stuff here should work
}
```

**Second solution:**

Otherwise if you want to use keydown you can use timestamp to prevent events update faster than what you can see (and it's more comfortable because you can tweak it).

Before your update function

```
var lastCheck = Date.now();
function update()
{
  if ( Date.now() - lastCheck > 200 ) // 200 is 200ms, tweak this
  {
    // old stuff inside
  }
}
```

**And a tip:**

Then a tip I can give you it's to not use if if if if like you do and look for better solution in this case you can use array and save the index of your position inside the array just moving this index

```
var pos = [ 10, 50, 150 ]; // 10 is top pos and 150 bot pos
var currentPosId = 0; // player y is pos[ currentPosId ]
```

Then in you update function you check keys and do currentPosId++ or -- I let you find how to do it (and if you add other pos later it'll be more comfortable for tweak and adding positions).

Comment: Thank you very much! For some reason the second solution didn't work, and of course I will take in consideration your tip!